# Numbering all rows in MySQL table using loop and cursor

Tags: mysql, loops, serialization, cursor

I have a table called "post". It has a column named "ID". It has to be numbered serial-wise normally, but because of some programming requirements, the column gets deranged, and at that time I need to re-number the column again, serial wise. There is no other Primary key.

I tried many methods using Cursor and Looping but to no avail.

Can anyone suggest any method. Please include details.

Comment: Are there other tables that references this `ID` column? Is this an autoincrement column?

Answer (score 0):

First you can just delete that column's data fully, tyr to execute following command:-

```
UPDATE table_name, (select @row_number:= 0) AS t
SET id = (SELECT @row_number := @row_number + 1);
```

For deleting that column's data you can simply use following command:-

```
UPDATE tab SET id = NULL;
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, may i know what is "t" and "tab"

Comment: `t` is just an alias or an identifier. you can choose it of your choice, and `tab` is your table_name.